# Excel VBA; Search rows grabbing values and pasting them into another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have two workbooks;

(WB1) with two sheets; "Input" and "Output"

and

(MacroWB) with the macro and a "Column Header" list.

Example file:  "Messy" sheet = input, "Organized" = output

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-leh2Ii2uh9bDBFbDBHbGcxbUU/view?usp=sharing

I need help coding a macro to do the following:

1) Create a loop to go through each row of the "Input" sheet searching for values matching cells in the "Column Header" list.

2) When a matching value is found; take the data from the cell immediately to it's right (in the "Input" sheet) and paste it into the corresponding column of the "Output" worksheet.

3) Once every "Column Header" item has been searched/pasted for that row; move to the next row of the "Input" sheet.  Rinse and repeat until all rows of the "Input" sheet have been searched/pasted.

Here is an example, the letters are to be column headers and the numbers are to be copied to the appropriate "Output" sheet column.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-leh2Ii2uh9TXRGTnFDRU1jY0U/view?usp=sharing

Keep in mind that the actual data file has ~50 columns and ~3000 rows.
Also that the data is not all Letter/Numbers like the table above, it is more like the data in the linked .xlsx file.

If there is anything I haven't been clear about, please ask and I will try my best to clarify.  Also I may be WAY over thinking this, if so.. please let me know.

THANK YOU ANYONE THAT CAN GET ME GOING IN THE CORRECT DIRECTION!!!

-Joe

Comment: Your question is too vague, it is highly unlikely you will get an answer. Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: Ok, I tried to be specific, sorry..  I'll try to edit it to be a more direct question

Answer (score 0):

Skip the the VBA and use Text to Columns the Data tab. I'malways copying html and its works 99% of the time. If the html is pretty and properly formated you may get away with using the fixed width option, otherwise gor for the delimted and choose "tab". If tab doesn't work try using spaces, assuming that your cells don't contain spaces.

The other option that I've had work on rare occasions that text to columns doesn't is simply saving the text in word and saving as rtf and then opening that in notepad++ (which everyone should have.) Copy from ++ to excel and that usually fixes the problem.

EDIT: If you right click before pasting and click "paste special" this regularly helps with html pasting.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample file, I used the following formula in `A2` of `Organized` sheet (assumed 50 as max columns in `Messy`):

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET(Messy!A1,0,MATCH(Organized!A$1,OFFSET(Messy!A1,0,0,1,50), )),"")
```

Dragging it to `H11` produced the following result:

[image]

The sample data is not complete, and some 'tags' in `Messy` sheet are not consistent (SiteID vs SITE_ID), but it should help you get started.

Comment: This is great!  Now I just need to figure out how to incorporate this into my macro!  Thank you